# Importing data from Informix DB to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, informix

Configured Informix drivers (32-bit) ODBC on my local machine and trying to import the data to SQL Server using SQL Server IMPORT and export wizard.

I selected source tables and views(steps in SQL import): 
When I click on preview I'm getting the error:

```
The preview data could not be retrieved.
Additional Information:
Error[42000][Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A syntax error has occurred.(iclit09b.dll)
```

How can I fix the error? FYI - There are many tables to import.

Comment: The message 'A syntax error has occurred' is Informix's "I don't understand what you said" message — it can occur for many reasons, some good, some bad.  Fundamentally, though, the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard sent some SQL to Informix that Informix didn't understand syntactically.  That probably means it used a T-SQL construct that Informix doesn't support (or the version of Informix you're using doesn't support — do you know which version of the Informix server you're working with?).  It isn't a problem with a table not existing (but maybe the Wizard used `[owner].table` notation).

Comment: It may be tricky to discover what SQL the Wizard generated, but if we can discover that, it might be simplest to diagnose where to go next.  However, the chances are that if the Wizard doesn't generate acceptable SQL by default, there isn't a way to change it to generate something different.  (However, it would be of interest to me to know what SQL was generated.)  If you can find the SQL, add it to the question, please.